# What do I need to do to create a self hosted NuGet feed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-server

I would like to create a custom nuget feed at work, but the computer that I want to host it from doesn't have IIS installed and I can't get it installed either.  So I wanted to create my own self-hosted feed, but I'm not sure where to start.  I already have a visualSVN server running on this computer, so I know that apache is already installed. Is there a way to host a nuget feed without IIS?

Comment: any reason why you don't consider a hosted solution such as MyGet.org?

Comment: company won't let us use something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a share. See the section **Creating Local Feeds** [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).

So, if your share is located at `\\server\nugetfeed`, replace `c:\LocalNuGetFeed` in the example with that location.

Comment: I was hoping to get it working over the web, but I'll give that a try

Comment: @scott - You may have to map the share to a drive letter if the network syntax doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a local feed running just from a directory on the computer. Once the packages are in a folder, you then need to add that folder as a local NuGet feed in Visual Studio.

Here are a couple of links describing the process:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

and this one is a bit older but still relevant I believe:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/10/21/hosting-your-own-local-and-remote-nupack-feeds.aspx

Comment: can I access that feed from other computers?

Comment: Well, it depends on if those other computers have access to the network share you set up. Are they co-workers computers that are the same network? If so, then most likely yes, but again, it depends on your network setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could install [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=34679). It could be a simpler solution worth a try if you already know you cannot put the full IIS on the machine.

Unless the same reasons you can't install IIS apply to IIS Express...

Comment: I was able to install iis express, but I didn't get a chance to set up a nuget feed with it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it may be too late at this point, my company's product [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) was designed for hosting private NuGet feeds and ships with an integrated web server - and it looks like the free edition will suit your use case just fine.